# htaccess RewriteRule passes index.php instead of string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I'm trying to learn about .htaccess RewriteRules and am facing the following issue:

"/home" should open "index.php?page=home"

and I have a php $_GET['page'] inside "index.php", but it passes "index.php" instead of "home" every time.

Here are the files

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

index.php PHP part

```
<?php

        if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $path = $_GET['page'] . ".php";
            if (file_exists($path)) {
                include($path);
            }
            else {
                echo "File not found: " . $path;
            }
        }
        else {
            include("home.php");
        }

?>
```

The output is always:

```
File not found: index.php.php
```

I face this issue on both: web-server and apache.

Any suggestions? I'll update my question with more info if necessary.

Comment: Try this `RewriteRule ^(.*)(/|)$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]` (I didnt test this on our server, but its very similar to something we have)

Comment: If you have a KNOWN set of pages, you could get away with something like `RewriteRule ^(home|about|catalog)(/|)$ /$1.php [QSA,L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must skip existing files and directories from your rewrite rule to avoid looping the rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.+?)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It works! You fixed it double. It works by just adding "QSA" at the end, and it works (without "QSA") when adding the RewriteConditions. Thanks :)